# excel sort columns in groups of 2

Tags: excel, sorting, excel-formula

I've a data in a row looking like this ->

```
5 0.1 3 0.5 9 17 1 0.1...
```

These are in groups of two, i.e., 0.1 is associated for 5 & 0.5 for 3 & so on

I want to sort the row in groups of two ->

```
1 0.1 3 0.5 5 0.1 9 17
```

Comment: Seems to me that transposing these into two columns then sorting would be best.  Is there a reason you would want this to remain in one row?

Comment: @ScottCraner but how to transfer them into different rows

Comment: My method two in my answer would be faster it you want to keep the single row.  Do you want the final to be in two Columns?

Comment: I added a method three that would address moving it into columns.

Answer (score 1):

This is a real formula hack but it solves your question as posted **at face value**.

There is a caveat that if there are ties in numbers, this will not work as accurately as your sample data.

Formulas are explained below the picture:

[image]

1. A5 -> `=A1`, then drag over skipping columns
2. A7 -> `=IF(ISBLANK(A5),A1,"")`, then drag over all columns
3. A4 -> `=IFERROR(RANK(A5,$A$5:$H$5),"")`, then drag over all columns
4. B6 -> `=IF(B4="",A4,"")`, then drag over all columns
5. A9 -> `=COUNT(A1:H1)/2`, rest of columns are just math.
6. A10 -> `=HLOOKUP(A9,$A$4:$H$5,2,0)`
7. B10 -> `=HLOOKUP(B9,$A$6:$H$7,2,0)`
8. copy A10:B10, over for each two columns.

Comment: I did it in two steps with sort on both cells, see my second method. :P

Answer (score 1):

Three methods depending on actual data structure

**Method 1:**

If the cells on which you wish to sort are not duplicates, you could do this:

In A2 put:

```
=A1
```

In B2 put:

```
=IF(MOD(COLUMN(),2) = 0,A1+(B1/1000),B1)
```

Then drag the whole width of the data:

[image]

Copy and paste just the values on row 2. Then sort horizontally on row 2:

[image]

Then you can delete row 2

---

**Method 2:**

If there are duplicates then this two step process will get you then list desired

In A2 put:

```
=IF(AND(MOD(COLUMN(),2),A1<>""),A1+(B1/10000),"")
```

In A3 put:

```
=IFERROR(IF(MOD(COLUMN(),2),INT(SMALL(2:2,ROUNDUP(COLUMN()/2,0))),(SMALL(2:2,ROUNDUP(COLUMN()/2,0))-INT(SMALL(2:2,ROUNDUP(COLUMN()/2,0))))*10000),"")
```

And copy across all columns. Row 3 will be your sorted list:

[image]

The advantage to this method is that you can paste the values of the list in row one and it will calculate the correct sort order on calculate.  There is no copying and pasting over formulas.

---

**Method 3:**

If you want to go the column route then:

In one column put:

```
=OFFSET($A$1,0,(ROW(1:1)-1)*2)
```

In the second:

```
=OFFSET($A$1,0,(ROW(1:1)*2-1))
```

Then copy down sufficient to get all the values.

[image]

Then copy and paste the values anywhere you want and then sort.

Comment: love it. sophisticated, yet clean :) ... much better than my total hack! :)